# NodeJS display single array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to only show one element in an array when defining. for example, my user schema is:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: String,
    studio: { type: String, required: true },
    comments: [
      {
        quantity: String,
        received: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        collected: { type: String, default: "At Reception" }
      }
    ],
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

and the following loop will list all users, their email, name, etc. :

```
<% for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= users[i].studio %></td>
     <td><%= users[i].name %></td>
     <td><%= users[i].email %></td>
     <td><%= users[i].comments %></td>
<% } %>
```

but the `users[i].comments` displays the entire array and I only want it to display `collected` element - currently displays this:

```
{
    received: 2017-12-13T08:51:14.914Z,
    collected: 'At Reception',
    quantity: '5',
    _id: 5a30ea0253432220138b4b89
}
```

I've tried `<td><%= users[i].comments.collected %></td>` but this results in nothing being shown.

EDIT: As Rashad has made me realise, what I actually want to do is show every single users comments with the value collected that have been made (to which I would use an `if` statement to filter them).

Comment: You defined `comments` as array, so how can you use `users[i].comments.collected` ? What's your goal? To show somehow entire `comments` array or only first element of `comments` array?

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm new to this. I want to display all comments that have been entered by users, so I will be able to do an if statement that will show only comments with the collected value of 'At Reception'...so basically trying to find all comments with the value 'collected'

Comment: If you want to display all of them, you should rename the question to say so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `<%= users[i].comments[0].collected %>`, comments[0] <- first item on your comments array

Comment: thanks, that displays something! not what I was looking for though which is my mistake i think as Rashad made me realise. I'm looking to display every single comment that has ever been made by users (i'd then do an if statement to display only those that are 'At Reception' as the collected value

Answer (score 0):

You could map over the comments array. I am not sure if it is possible in that templating language but in regular js it would be:

`users[i].comments.map((comment) => comment.collected)`

Edited to include an example in ejs

```
<% for(var i=0; i < users.length; i++) { %>
  <% comments = user[i].comments.map(function(comment) {
      return comment.collected;
  }) -%>
   <tr>
     <td><%= users[i].studio %></td>
     <td><%= users[i].name %></td>
     <td><%= users[i].email %></td>
     <td><%= comments %></td>
<% } %>
```